# Delete rows that are older than 30 days but keep unique row

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `elos_old` that has the following fields: `id`, `username`, `elo` and `created_at` where `username` is a string and `created_at` is a timestamp.

I want to delete all rows that are older than 30 days but keep the most recent row for each username if there is only one row with that username. So if username `userA` has only one row that is older than 30 days, I don't want to delete that row. The same username can have multiple rows due to different elo ratings on daily basis.

I tried the following query:

```
DELETE FROM elos_old
WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND username NOT IN (
    SELECT username FROM (
        SELECT username, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM elos_old
        GROUP BY username
        HAVING cnt = 1
    ) as single_usernames
);
```

But every time I run it new rows are affected even though no new data has been added to the table.

Comment: What if the user has some rows newer than 30 days, and 5 rows older than 30 days? Should it delete all the old rows, or keep 1 of them?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @Barmar it should delete all old rows in that case. Basically if it's older than 30 days and the user doesn't have more entries/rows it shouldn't delete the users only entry even if it's older than 30 days.

Comment: The problem with your query is if they have no new rows, and more than 1 old row, the NOT IN subquery won't return them, so all the old rows will be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery should return a table containing usernames and the date of the oldest row to keep. For users with rows newer than 30 days, this would be the oldest one newer than 30 days ago. For users with no new rows, this would be the newest one older than 30 days.

You can then join this with the table and delete all the rows with dates older than the date from the subquery.

```
WITH threshold AS (
    -- Use either newest old row, or oldest new row, whichever is newer
    SELECT username, MAX(keep_date) AS keep_date
    FROM (
        -- oldest row for users with new rows
        SELECT username, MIN(created_at) AS keep_date
        FROM elos_old
        WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        GROUP BY username
    
        UNION ALL
    
        -- newest row for users with old rows
        SELECT username, MAX(created_at) AS keep_date
        FROM elos_old
        WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        GROUP BY username)
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY username
)
DELETE t1
FROM elos_old AS t1
JOIN threshold AS t2 ON t1.username = t2.username AND t1.created_date < t2.keep_date
```